# download my all/selected question thread

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am planning to write blogs on my real time problems that I asked on Stack Overflow. Is there any feature where I can select my questions and answers and download it in word format.

Comment: This might help you out - http://www.stackprinter.com/

Comment: this is good , but only one question at a time.

Comment: this might help you [StackTack WordPress Plugin - Embed Stack Exchange Questions in Your Blog.](http://stackapps.com/q/3237)

Answer (score 4):

This already exists (sort of), you can get all your questions and answers via the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/):

- [questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/252975/questions?site=stackoverflow),
- [answers](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/252975/answers?site=stackoverflow)

Comment: questions and answers link shows something like JSON string and API link doesn't take to any specific api page. Can you give proper link?

Comment: @ImranRizvi Hmm? The API link works fine, what do you mean by specific API page? And yes the questions and answers links are json strings.

Comment: I meant the page where I can see something like "how to use api to download all your question and answers"

Comment: @ImranRizvi Read the [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Note this is an API, you'll need to write some code to get what you need.

Comment: oh so you mean to say I have to implement the API and write some function to get the given JSON quesiton and answer strings.

Comment: @ImranRizvi Yes.